# what does "replica:0" mean in tensorflow code "tf.device('job:ps/replica:0/task:0/')"

Tags: tensorflow

Recently I am studying distributed tensorflow. I am confused about the device name of tensorflow.

For example, the device name

`"job:ps/replica:0/task:0/"`

I know what do `"job:ps"` and `"task:0"` mean, but I don't know `"replica:0"`.
And I found that always be `"replica:0"`, I nerver seen that `"replica:1"` or `"replica:n"`

Is it always `"replica:0"` ? Is it useless? What is `"replica:0"` for?